# Allow wildcards / globbing in Tag Filters

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, tag-filters

The Favourite Tags sidebar on a given site allows selection of some exact tags as favourites, to show more of, etc.

[image]

Clicking the [advanced subscriptions button](https://stackexchange.com/filters):

[image]

Ok, but I still have to specify individual tags.

If I want to see *all* questions tagged matching `python*` ([python3.x](/questions/tagged/python3.x), [python3.4](/questions/tagged/python3.4), [python2.4](/questions/tagged/python2.4), and so on), I need to select each and every one individually.

Since `*` asterisks are disallowed in tag names, could using a `*` asterisk in the tag name field result in a glob, to include all tags matching the wildcard?

Comment: Per-site favorite tags [allow * wildcards already](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/). Not sure about the SE-wide filter, though.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The SE-wide filter returns 0 results if I try a 'python*' filter.

Answer (score 3):

This does not use the tag filters but, if you type `[status*]` into the search bar at top right, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> you should see it explode into:

```
[status-completed] or [status-bydesign] or [status-declined] or [status-norepro] or [status-deferred] or [status-planned] or [status-review] or [status-reproduced]
```

which I think, with another <kbd>Enter</kbd>, might meet your immediate requirement.